# Como fazer o site responder ao texto? Ex: usuário X: "oi usuário X" caso não seja este usuário "oi usuário desconhecido"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>
<input type="button" name="button" value="wert" id="button" class="button" Onclick = "wert()"/>

<script>
function wert() {
var o = document.GetElementById('text').value;
var nome = "antonio";
var ok = nome = o;
var ok = true;

if(ok){
alert("oi antonio")
else {alert(oi desconhecido)}
  }

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso ai está cheio de erros de sintaxe. Falta chave antes do `else`, aspas no texto, parêntesis,...

Comment: Além dos erros de sintaxe, sua condição sempre será verdadeira, pois a variável ok recebe um true;

Answer (score 2):

Olá Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, espero ter ajudado.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>

<input type="button" name="button" value="wert" id="button" class="button"/>

<script>


function wert() {
var text = document.getElementById('text').value;

 if(text != ''){
  alert('Olá '+text);
 }
 else{
  alert('Olá Usuario Desconhecido');
 }
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  wert();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está sobrescrevendo a variável ok, e ela será sempre true. Além disso, você está pegando o valor do campo, porém não o está utilizando. Para utilizar o nome que é passado pelo input, segue um exemplo:

```
function wert() { 
 var nome = document.getElementById('text').value;
 if (nome) {
   alert(`Oi ${nome}`);
  } else
   alert('Oi desconhecido');
  }
```

Aconselho a estudar o básico de javascript antes de passar a integrá-lo com o HTML.
Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Existem erros de sintaxe e lógica como já foi comentado acima. Revise alguns conceitos e se possível indentar o código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>
   <input type="button" name="button" value="wert" id="button" class="button" Onclick = "wert()"/>

   <script>
      function wert() {

         // Métodos são por padrão definidos com a inicial MINÚSCULA, e faz diferença em linguagens caseSensitive
         var o = document.getElementById('text').value;
         var nome = "antonio";

        /* Em relação a operadores '=' significa atribuição e '==' comparação
         * Nesse caso, se a variável 'nome' for igual à 'o', 'ok' será true, se não false
         */
         var ok = nome == o;

         // As chaves delimitam um bloco de comando, por isso a indentação do código é importante.
         if(ok){
            alert('Oi antonio!');
         } else {
            alert('Oi desconhecido!');
         }

      }
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```